# How to pass bundled styles file to tinyMCE?

Tags: css, razor, tinymce, nopcommerce

I want to pass bundled CSS file to tinyMCE instead of specifying files individually in the `content_css` section *(please see this for reference [tinymce.com](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css))*.

But the name of the bundled file is generated automatically. I am not able to specify the name in the code. Is there any way to do this? Or can we specify what should be the name of the bundled CSS file?